# How to calculate difference for only first value in a group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
ticket num loadtype   start                   diff                       end                                        
2       1   FIRST   12/28/18 7:40 PM    0 days 06:05:48.928732000   12/29/18 1:45 AM
2       2   MIDDLE  12/28/18 7:40 PM    0 days 09:21:17.652138000   12/29/18 5:01 AM
2       3   LAST    12/28/18 7:40 PM    0 days 13:11:39.585263000   12/29/18 8:51 AM
4 .     4 . FIRST   12/29/18 7:00 AM .  1 days 00:00:00.000000000   12/30/18 7:00 AM
```

The dataframe is grouped by 'ticket', which has multiple loads. I want to only calculate the difference between end and start for the FIRST load of each ticket, and persist that through all the rest of the loads for that ticket.

So I want

```
ticket num loadtype   start                   diff                       end                                        
2      1    FIRST   12/28/18 7:40 PM    0 days 06:05:48.928732000   12/29/18 1:45 AM
2      2    MIDDLE  12/28/18 7:40 PM    0 days 06:05:48.928732000   12/29/18 5:01 AM
2      3    LAST    12/28/18 7:40 PM    0 days 06:05:48.928732000   12/29/18 8:51 AM
4 .    4 .  FIRST   12/29/18 7:00 AM .  1 days 00:00:00.000000000   12/30/18 7:00 AM
```

How would I do this in pandas? Would I have to use a groupby followed by an apply of some sort?

Comment: "The dataframe is grouped by 'ticket'" which isn't shown in your question. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works if your `ticket` groups appear in the given order

```
# preset with na Time
df['diff'] = pd.NaT

# update the FIRST loadtype
df.loc[df.loadtype.eq('FIRST'),'diff'] = (df['end'] - df['start'])

# ffill
df['diff'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['diff'].ffill())
```

Output:

```
   num loadtype               start     diff                 end
0    1    FIRST 2018-12-28 19:40:00 06:05:00 2018-12-29 01:45:00
1    2   MIDDLE 2018-12-28 19:40:00 06:05:00 2018-12-29 05:01:00
2    3     LAST 2018-12-28 19:40:00 06:05:00 2018-12-29 08:51:00
```